# Retrieve the total number of objects in a NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data

Is there a way to find out the total number of objects in a `NSManagedObjectContext`? I can't do it easily with a `NSFetchRequest`as it won't span over different entities.

What am trying to do is to view the state of my `NSManagedObjectContext` for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for all the objects in an `NSManagedObjectContext`, you can use the `registeredObjects` property. Note that `NSManagedObjectContext` acts like a scratch pad so this only returns the objects in the `NSManagedObjectContext`, not all the items in the persistent store.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to grab `context.persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectModel.entities` then iterate through and do a suitable `countForFetcgRequest:...` for each, summing the total. If it's for debug logging I guess it's quite likely you'll end up wanting to do something with the full list of entities anyway.